# Is there any way to get the list of validators used in moongoose schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I want to get the list of validators that is used in a moongoose schema? Something like

```
const userModel = {
 firstName: {
 type:String,
 required: true
 }
}

// is there any method to get validations like

console.log(userModel.getValidators())

Output:

{
  firstName: {required: true ....etc},
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you setup your model using the `SchemaFactory.createForClass` method from a class with a `@Schema` decorator as shown in [the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#model-injection), you can export the schema. If you then, import the schema and access its `obj` property, you can extract information about the field.

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type CatDocument = Cat & Document;

@Schema()
export class Cat {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  name: string;

  @Prop()
  age: number;

  @Prop()
  breed: string;
}

export const CatSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Cat);
```

```
import { CatSchema } from './cat.schema';

console.log(CatSchema.obj.name.required);  // true
console.log(CatSchema.obj.age.type.name);  // 'Number'
```